# What should i do if i have an error of fetching api using http?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, api, http

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgSdZ.png)
When i am fetching data from api using http, this error always shows up i guess it is related to xcode

I tried to add this

```
"<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>"
```

in info_plist folder also upgraded all libraries

Comment: Share error logs instead of error logs image.